# 444...44+2×888...88+4 is perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

> Prove that $\underbrace{444\dots44}_{2n} + 2×\underbrace{888\dots88}_{n} + 4$ is a perfect square

For me I dunno how to do this, I could only managed to notice that 4 is perfect square. Please help

Comment: $56$ is not a perfect square...

Comment: Please check the problem because, as stated, it does not appear to be correct when $n=1$.

Comment: Please name an example where it is a perfect square

Comment: The result to be proven is erroneous for all $n$ I have tested !

Comment: It is never a perfect square.

Comment: @JeanMarie It is also [wrong for all $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3471616/) 

Comment: the question has been edited (factor of $2$ inserted) since the above comments were made, and I have edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in the comments, the proposition as stated is not true, but we can say this:

$$\underbrace{666...666}_{n-1}7^2=\left(6\times\dfrac{10^n-1}9+1\right)^2=\left(\dfrac{6\times10^n+3}{9}\right)^2=\left(\dfrac {2\times10^n+1}{3}\right)^2$$

$$=\dfrac{4\times10^{2n}+4\times10^n+1}9=4\times\dfrac{10^{2n}-1}9+4\times\dfrac{10^n-1}9+1=\underbrace{444...444}_n\underbrace{888...888}_{n-1}9$$

---

**Addendum in response to editing of question:**

My answer above was a reponse to the original question,

which asked to prove that $\underbrace{444\dots44}_{2n} + \underbrace{888\dots88}_{n} + 4$ is a perfect square, which [it never is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3471616/why-is-underbrace444-dots44-2n-underbrace888-dots88-n-4-never-a).

Now that the question asks to prove that  $\underbrace{444\dots44}_{2n} + \color{blue}{2\times}\underbrace{888\dots88}_{n} + 4$ is a perfect square,

note that $m^2=\underbrace{444\dots44}_{2n} + \color{black}{2\times}\underbrace{888\dots88}_{n} + 4=4\times\left(\dfrac{10^{2n}-1}9\right)+2\times8\times\dfrac{10^n-1}9+4$

$\implies\dfrac94m^2=(10^{2n}-1)+4(10^n-1)+9= 10^{2n}+4\times10^n+4=(10^{n}+2)^2$

$\implies\dfrac32m=10^{n}+2\implies m=\dfrac23(10^n+2),$

and $10^n+2$ is divisible by $3$ because $10$ leaves remainder $1$ when divided by $3,$ so $m$ is an integer.

Comment: Well done for working out what the question should have been.

Comment: Hey, guy. I'm so sorry for troubling you. But I forget about the 2× in front of 888..88 that's why it is wrong. I'm very sorry for taking your time

Comment: @user635988 It would be better if you asked a new question but the answer is that the new expression equals $$\left(\frac23 (2+10^n)\right)^2$$ so you only need to show that $2+10^n$ is divisible by $3$.